Integrate WebAuthn4J with Spring OAuth2, Client getting authorization_request_not_found Exception
I got a OAuth2 auth server with WebAuthn authentication provider.
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.webauthn4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>webauthn4j-spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

Below is my configuration:
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
    http
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                            new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    )
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        throws Exception {
    http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    
    http.with(WebAuthnLoginConfigurer.webAuthnLogin(), (customizer) -> {
        customizer
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .credentialIdParameter("credentialId") 
            .clientDataJSONParameter("clientDataJSON")
            .authenticatorDataParameter("authenticatorData")
            .signatureParameter("signature")
            .clientExtensionsJSONParameter("clientExtensionsJSON")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .attestationOptionsEndpoint()
            .rp()
            .name("My Login App")
            .and()
            .pubKeyCredParams(
                new PublicKeyCredentialParameters(PublicKeyCredentialType.PUBLIC_KEY, COSEAlgorithmIdentifier.RS256),
                new PublicKeyCredentialParameters(PublicKeyCredentialType.PUBLIC_KEY, COSEAlgorithmIdentifier.ES256)
            )
            .authenticatorSelection()
            .authenticatorAttachment(AuthenticatorAttachment.PLATFORM)
            .residentKey(ResidentKeyRequirement.REQUIRED)
            .userVerification(UserVerificationRequirement.REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .attestation(AttestationConveyancePreference.DIRECT)
            .extensions()
            .credProps(true)
            .uvm(true)
            .and()
            .assertionOptionsEndpoint();
    });

    http.headers(headers -> {
        headers.permissionsPolicy(config -> config.policy("publickey-credentials-get=(self)"));
        headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable);
    });

    http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) 
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/dashboard").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        )
        .logout(customizer -> {
            customizer
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        });

    return http.build();
}

This is my client:
    spring:
      application:
        name: spring-oauth-client
      security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            provider:
              oauth-server:
                issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
                authorizationUri: ${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oauth-server.issuer-uri}/oauth2/authorize
                tokenUri: ${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oauth-server.issuer-uri}/oauth2/token
            registration:
              messaging-client-oidc:
                provider: oauth-server
                client-name: WebAPp
                client-id: web-client-id
                client-secret: secret
                client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
                authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                redirect-uri: http://spring-oauth-client:9001/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc
                scope:
                  - profile
                  - openid

If I login using the username and password I can complete the OIDC flow, my client managed to exchange the accesstoken. However if I use webauthn to login, the webauthn login is correct. I managed to redirect back the authorization code and state But the client will hit:
    2024-11-02T08:46:23.457+08:00 TRACE 99184 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (8/18)
    2024-11-02T08:46:23.457+08:00 TRACE 99184 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (9/18)
    2024-11-02T08:46:23.457+08:00 TRACE 99184 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (10/18)
    2024-11-02T08:46:23.458+08:00 TRACE 99184 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-1] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

    org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 
            at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:198) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:198) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]

I tried to set two domain differently still unable to resolve this. In the oauth client I also tried this:
@Override
public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.info("Removing authorization request for session");
    logger.info("============={} " , request.getSession().getAttribute("org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST"));
    return delegate.removeAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
}

It printed null that is why throw the exception. When I directed to auth server I can see this:
2024-11-02T10:10:13.939+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-5] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : Saving authorization request: _kPxm3y1G0Slq-ZjCZyxwvJxqB5MVHhPr0EydGJa6qo=
2024-11-02T10:10:13.940+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-5] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : 1F15013047D2886E11E60602F54237FC 
2024-11-02T10:10:13.940+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-5] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : =============org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest@cd05941 
2024-11-02T10:10:13.940+08:00 DEBUG 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=web-client-id&scope=profile%20openid&state=_kPxm3y1G0Slq-ZjCZyxwvJxqB5MVHhPr0EydGJa6qo%3D&redirect_uri=http://spring-oauth-client:9001/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc&nonce=RpXVQtMXHMZQ7VbJi1B-J-uRj4Fum_BrKCDA1xwM8iE

After authenticated by webauthn:
2024-11-02T10:13:58.831+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-9] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : Removing authorization request for session
2024-11-02T10:13:58.831+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-9] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : =============null 
2024-11-02T10:13:58.847+08:00 TRACE 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-9] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 

This is when I login using username and password:
2024-11-02T10:15:15.357+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-7] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : Removing authorization request for session
2024-11-02T10:15:15.357+08:00  INFO 33756 --- [spring-oauth-client] [nio-9001-exec-7] stomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository : =============org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest@7a4ca896
